# Grouped Product - Catalog Pricing - Starting at

Tags: grouped-products, pricing, advanced-pricing

I have recently started to manage a new Magento store, It was built by an agency and there is very little documentation. We are currently running 2.2.3 Enterprise.

It's my understanding if I had several simples in a grouped product, In the catalog and the grouped product would show 'Price starting at ....' Starting with the lowest price. Currently, the site shows nothing at all, its just blank.

Does anyone have any ideas where I would start looking to rectify this?

Thanks! :)